# What activities will require an Excelsior covid pass?

Tags: new-york-state, covid-19

[NY's website](https://covid19vaccine.health.ny.gov/excelsior-pass) and re-opening plan is difficult for me to understand, and the website is very opaque.  What sorts of activities will require an Excelsior pass or recent negative covid test, and will these requirements vary by county or municipality?

Comment: can you add a link to the site please?

Comment: @DavidSiegel done.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be pretty vague at the moment, and I've copied what I see as relevant to the question.

> **If you're attending an event or business and you're not sure if you
> can use Excelsior Pass—please check with the business or venue in
> advance.**

> There will be many opportunities to use Excelsior Pass, with more
> coming soon!
>
> Currently, several industries are currently or expected to require
> proof of COVID-19 vaccination or negative test results for entry.
>
> Once you and your party enter an establishment, you will still
> be asked to follow other State guidance regarding social distancing or
> face coverings.
>
> **Weddings and Catered Events**:
> Weddings and catered events can operate
> at 50 percent capacity, with no more than 150 people per event, as
> long as all patrons are tested before the event. Specifically, patrons
> or guests must have received a negative COVID-19 PCR test that was
> taken within 72 hours of the start time of the event or an authorized
> antigen test performed within 6 hours of the event start time.
>
> **Major Stadiums & Arenas**:
> At major stadiums and arenas, spectators must
> show proof of a negative COVID-19 PCR test taken within 72 hours,
> COVID-19 antigen test taken within 6 hours, or proof of full
> vaccination (to be fully vaccinated you must have completed your
> vaccine series at least 14 days prior). As of April 1, smaller sports
> venues can also reopen with spectators under the same guidelines for
> proof of a negative test or vaccination. Easily retrieve and save
> proof of vaccination or a negative COVID-19 test with Excelsior Pass.
>
> **Events, Arts & Entertainment Venues**: Starting April 2, venues can
> welcome more people with proof of vaccination or a recent negative
> COVID test for entry. Easily retrieve and save proof of vaccination or
> a negative COVID-19 test with Excelsior Pass.